NaN values when I try to sum values by polygons using ST_SummaryStatsAgg in SQL
I am trying to sum values by polygon region from a raster in a SQL Postgres database, but I am getting NaN values for some regions. If I run zonal statistics for the raster and polygon data in QGIS the values are summed correctly for all regions. How can I fix the NaN values so that I can correctly sum the raster data in my Postgres database?
The database process is as follows:

Import the raster file into a table in Pgadmin using:

raster2pgsql -s 54009 -C -I -Y -M -t 250x250 -F raster.tif zonalstats.raster_test | psql -h localhost -d db_database -U postgres -p 5432


Import the region polygon file:

shp2pgsql -g geometry -I -s 54009 regions.shp zonalstats.regions_test | psql -h localhost -d db_database -U postgres -p 5432

These import fine.

Then I run the following query in Pgadmin, which sums the values by region and puts them into a new table called test_stats:

CREATE TABLE zonalstats.test_stats AS 
  SELECT
    CAST (geo.gid AS INTEGER) AS geom_id,
    geo.geometry AS geometry,
    COUNT(1) AS n_tiles,
    (ST_SummaryStatsAgg(ST_Clip(raster.rast, geo.geometry, true), 1, true)).* 
  FROM
    zonalstats.raster_test AS raster
    JOIN
    zonalstats.regions_test AS geo ON
      ST_Intersects(geo.geometry, raster.rast)
  GROUP BY
     geom_id, geometry
;


I then query the new zonalstats.test_stats table to view the results.

The image below shows a sample set of results compared to those from using QGIS Zonal Statistics


If I export the raster file from QGIS by simply right clicking on the layer and saving as, this new version of the raster does not generate NaN values and the statistics are summed correctly. Does anyone know why this is? I don't really want to go through this process as it involves duplicating all of my raster files.

You can try changing the parameter from true to false to see if the issue is due to a very strict clipping. ST_Clip(raster.rast, geo.geometry, false)
